# How do I define a search scope "Display Group" for a Site definition

Tags: sharepoint, search, site-definition

Within each site collection, it is possible to group search scopes for display in the site collections search box.

It is possible to modify this programmatically as well.

**Is it possible to define search scope "Display Groups" within a site definition?**

I will be creating 8000 odd site collections from this template and it would be nice not to have to write a powershell script/console app to do it. 
(releasing such things is a pain in our environment - whatever happend to the days when developers could just hack away at production servers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about a way to do it with XML, but if you can write code to do it a feature receiver may be a better option than a console app - since it's packaged in a WSP file the deployment process will be the same as for the site definition itself.